# RISC-V LLVM 13 Linker Error: `undefined hidden symbol: __math_oflowf`

Tags: llvm, riscv

I am trying to link some RISC-V code and I am getting the following error.

```
ld.lld-13: error: undefined hidden symbol: __math_oflowf
>>> referenced by sf_expm1.c
>>>               lib_a-sf_expm1.o:(expm1f) in archive /home/fabian/fp/tools/rv32gcv/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libm.a
>>> did you mean: __math_oflow
>>> defined in: /home/fabian/fp/tools/rv32gcv/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libm.a
```

I am using a GCC rv32gcv toolchain with `--gcc-toolchain` and `--sysroot` for the lib/inc. Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here? I can`t find anything online sadly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that it was due to a bug in an older version of the newlib library which the toolchain depends on. If you update the GCC toolchain to the latest release, it should be fixed.